# How do you use certmgr to add a certificate to Trusted Publishers in Excel?

Tags: windows, certificate

I have tried:

```
certmgrs /add myCert.cer /s /r localMachine root
```

I have tried several variations on that like: `localMachine` `trustedPublishers`

Everytime I try this on the command line it just loads the certmgr Utility Window. I can't see this command line call doing anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Best way to do this on the command line is as follows:

```
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" certificate.cer
```

The other answer here won't work in my situation.  I had to add via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following article for a start. It shows you how to create your own digital certs in MS office 2010.

1. [2010 Office - Create your own digital certificates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-your-own-digital-certificate-HP005249558.aspx)
2. [Add, remove, view a trusted publisher](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-remove-or-view-a-trusted-publisher-HA010034138.aspx)

You could do more search to find out how to add digital cert in Excel 2003, 2007 (not my preference of editiont though) as well.